# Reorder pandas DataFrame with specific rules

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

```
XList=[2,3,4,5,5,6]
YList=['A','A','A','B','A','A']
df = pd.DataFrame({'X':XList,
                   'Y':YList})

df

    X  Y
 0 10  A
 1  3  A
 2  4  A
 3  5  B
 4  5  A
 5  6  A
```

How can I reorder only Line 3 and 4 (case: same X-Value) so they are in ascedent order in Y (A,B) like this:

Everytime X-Values are equal it should reorder Y-Values.

```
    X   Y
0  10   A
1   3   A
2   4   A
3   5   A
4   5   B
5   6   A
```

Comment: does `df.sort(columns=['X','Y'])` do what you want?

Comment: @EdChum it is not really what I want. I want just to be able to sort the duplicates on X based on the Y-Values (ascending order if X is duplicate). I edited my question it was not clear, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sort only those values of `YList` where `XList` values are equal, here is the code:

```
>>> XList=[2,3,4,5,5,6]
>>> YList=['A','A','A','B','A','A']
>>> idx = []
>>> for i in range(len(XList)-1):
...    if XList[i]==XList[i+1]: idx.append(i)
...    else:
...       if len(idx)>=1:  
...         idx.append(i)
...         YList[idx[0]:idx[-1]+1] = sorted(YList[idx[0]:idx[-1]+1])
...         idx=[]
... 
>>> YList
['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A']
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'X':XList,
...                    'Y':YList})
>>> df
   X  Y
0  2  A
1  3  A
2  4  A
3  5  A
4  5  B
5  6  A
```

Comment: Nice way to solve thanks! I wonder if there is a way to solve using one line command. Are the one command lines usually faster than loops right?

Comment: I am not saying that it is not possible to do it using a one line command. There may be one. But the given case is very complex. We need to first find consecutive `XList` indices where `XList` values are equal. Then sort YList values for those indices and continue to find similar `XList` indices and sort `YList` until end of `XList`. For the given input this looks simple. But assume it for a list like that `[2,3,4,4,4,5,6,5,5,5,7,8,9,3,3,3,4,4,4,.....]`